Mercy of the world
Why Muhammad sm changed policy of tolerance of injustice to the policy of establishing justice by killing the culprits who were doing injustice to Muslims.

This is not one question but many. First, do you have reference that it really happened? Second, could Mohammad, himself, change policies? And then, was it in case of self-defense or only on being accidentally short-changed? Please sharpen your question, and maybe, split it into different questions.

@GyroGearloose I agree. The question is very confusing. Hope what UmH suggested answers it. Btw, just wanted to comment on could Mohammad, himself, change policies?: Yes, he can. His actions and orders regarding the religion are regarded as revelation, similar to how the Quran is and his saying can abrogate verses of the Quran as well. Even the intuition of the Prophet PBUH is regarded as revelation and can thus be used to "change policies".

@SyedM.Sannan "... are regarded as revelation, ...", well, this does not imply that Muhammad himself made the decision but revealed them. It is a very delicate, and possibly dangerous question.

Something the Prophet SAW gets as intuition, entirely with his consciousness is revelation of Allah. He is not getting an angel to him to reveal to him, no other source. His mere intuition generated by his very own individual conscious reveals to him the commandments of Allah amongst other sources of revelation.

@SyedM.Sannan "... is revelation of Allah. ...", yes exactly, and not initiated by the Prophet. To say otherwise (and that is why I said this question is dangerous) would be like the Christians do, putting Prophets next to the Almighty.

@GyroGearloose how do you differentiate something initiated by Allah and something not? As per theology, all actions are allowed by Allah so something coming in someone's intuition as revelation or whisper of satan both are allowed by Allah.

@SyedM.Sannan "how do you differentiate something initiated by Allah and something not?" I don't, but you do. You attribute the action to the Prophet, while he is only forwarding it. A mistaken thought that comes up easily. So please have mercy with those making the same mistake.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
